# Multiple sets intersection where objects contained at least in some of them are selected

Tags: python, set

Given N sets how can I select those objects, which contained at least in K (where K <= N) sets using python?

Comment: Please provide some code with your different rials.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level. You also need to state exactly what the problem is, what you expected, what you got, and any traceback.

Comment: For example I have 3 sets:
A = {a, b, c, d}
B = {d, c, m}
C = {k, m, a}

And suppose K=2. So I need some solution which outputs set, where elements contained in at least 2 sets from A, B, C:
{a, c, d, m}.

But I need this solution to work with different numbers of input sets and different K.

Comment: As other said, if you have done some tries, show us your code and where exactly you have problems. Otherwise, try tackling it yourself, you'll see it is not as difficult as it seems.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any ideas for solving this task.

Comment: In the example sets in your comment, what are `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.? Those are not built-in objects in Python. Do you mean to use `A = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard for us to give you an answer that matches your current knowledge of Python, since you show no effort of your own. But I'll give you a high-level hint here. If you need more details, first add some efforts of your own to the question.

Probably the easiest way to do your task in Python is to use the [Counter datatype](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). First you create an empty `Counter` object. Then you `update` the Counter object with each of your N sets. Then use the `items` method of the object to make your set elements with their numbers of occurrences in the sets into a list. Finally you loop over that list to extract the set elements that had at least K occurrences in the sets. (It is possible to do that looping and choosing without using `items` but I believe that using `items` is more pythonic.)

If you do not understand the `Counter` object, you could do the same thing yourself with Python's dictionaries, but it would be more work on your part. The main limitation on this approach is that your set elements must all be hashable objects in Python. This includes numbers, strings, and tuples, so that should not be a problem for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer nevertheless, I have not provided enough information (actually it's the first time I'm asking a question there and it wasn't clear for me how to do it properly).